# AppCmd command fail : Cannot find requested collection element

Tags: iis, iis-7

it tried to set application physical path by using the command line :

```
APPCMD set app "Default Web Site/SiteName" /applicationPool:MyAppPool  /[path='/'].physicalPath:C:\MySite
```

I got an error :

```
ERROR ( message:Cannot find requested collection element. )
```

The application pool and the site are already exist.

Please help.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score -2):

Try to run this command with the parameter:

```
/commitPath:apphost
```